# How can I hide some content based on user role in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jaas

I'm using JAAS and have applied security on some folders for different roles. I want to hide some navigation for different users because, although the pages are not accessible, the user can still see the links that he has no rights on? What's the simple way to achieve this in JSF? Do I need to call a method to check the role in the "rendered" property of each navigation link? Any sample code? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrent answer is here, may be helpful for someone else: [Is "isUserInRole" method related to JAAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648562/is-isuserinrole-method-related-to-jaas)

Answer (score 2):

Use `rendered` for view, take

```
rendered="#{userBean.role =='ADMIN'}"
```

also configure filter or use Spring security's filter to restrict them to access the URL

Comment: correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648562/is-isuserinrole-method-related-to-jaas

Comment: But for that one needs to define a userBean, and populate it when user logs in? But the above URL is a very simple approach :)