# Is "isUserInRole" method related to JAAS?

Tags: java, jsf, jaas

I've configured JAAS in glassfish 3.0 and used JDBCRealm for authenticating users. It's working properly and URL(s) are restricted. But the method
`#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('admin')}` always returns false, even when the logged in user is admin.I've set "admin" for both "group name" in my database and for "role name" in the mapping file and the user is admin. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a servlet container, [isUserInRole](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) is just a call to the [underlying servlet method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29). I would double-check the [role mappings](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#bncav) in the deployment descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for the URL, I was missing the <security-role> tag :) Thanks alot!